# Why is a lower bound given for the proof of $E(Y) = ne^{-\lambda} (1 + O(\lambda^2/n))$?

Tags: asymptotics, random-graphs

I am once again stuck on some asymptotics.

In this proof, it is assumed that $1/2\le \lambda \le n/2$.

First, it is shown that $$E(Y) \le ne^{-\lambda}e^{(\lambda/n)}.$$

Next, it is shown that $$ne^{-\lambda}e^{(-\lambda^2/n)} \le E(Y).$$

The conclusion is that $E(Y) = ne^{-\lambda} (1 + O(\lambda^2/n)).$

I don't understand why the lower bound is necessary here. Isn't it true that in this case, $e^{\lambda/n} = 1 + O(\lambda/n)$ because $$e^{\lambda/n} = 1 + \frac{{(\lambda/n)}^2}{2!} + \frac{{(\lambda/n)}^3}{3!} + \cdots \le 1 + \lambda/n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3}! + \cdots \right) = 1+e \frac{\lambda}{n} = 1+ O(\frac{\lambda}{n})?$$

In the inequality, I used the fact that $(\frac{\lambda}{n})^k \le \frac{\lambda}{n}$ since $\lambda \le \frac{n}{2}$.

Am I missing something here? Why is the lower bound needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upper bound shows that there is a function $g(n,\lambda) = O(\lambda/n)$ such that

$$
(ne^{-\lambda})^{-1} E(Y) - 1 \leq g(n,\lambda). \tag{1}
$$

However, in order to conclude that $(ne^{-\lambda})^{-1} E(Y) - 1 = O(\lambda/n)$, you need to know that

$$
\left|(ne^{-\lambda})^{-1} E(Y) - 1\right| \leq C\lambda/n \tag{2}
$$

for some constant $C$.

What if $(ne^{-\lambda})^{-1} E(Y) - 1 = -\lambda n$? Then we could just take $g(n,\lambda) = 0$, so $(1)$ would be true, but $(2)$ certainly wouldn't be.

The point of also showing that $ne^{-\lambda}e^{(-\lambda^2/n)} \le E(Y)$ is to find another function $h(n,\lambda) = O(\lambda/n)$ such that

$$
(ne^{-\lambda})^{-1} E(Y) - 1 \geq h(n,\lambda). \tag{3}
$$

Then, $(1)$ and $(3)$ together imply $(2)$, which is the desired result, because

$$
\left|(ne^{-\lambda})^{-1} E(Y) - 1\right| \leq \max\{|g(n,\lambda)|,|h(n,\lambda)|\} = O(\lambda/n).
$$

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that the definition of $g(x)=O(f(x))$ was that $|g(x)|<=C|f(x)|$, i.e. I forgot about the absolute values. I keep coming across states like above, for example $f(n)=g(n)[1+O(1/n)]$. Is there some sort of intuitive way of looking at these sort of statements? Should I be thinking that $f$ is $g$ + some part of $g$ that goes down as $1/n$? What do you imagine in your mind when you encounter such statements?

Comment: @theQman, A statement like that is a statement about [relative error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error). $f(n) = g(n)[1+O(1/n)]$ says that the relative error in approximating $f$ by $g$ is bounded by $C/n$ for some $C$.

Comment: Ah, that's much clearer. Thanks. One last thing, how does the lower bound allow us to finish the proof? I think what I'm asking is: why is $e^{-\lambda^2/n} \ge 1+C\lambda^2/n$?

Comment: @theQman, that follows from the Taylor series.

Comment: Doesn't the Taylor series gives us an upper bound for $e^{-\lambda^2/n}$? i.e. $e^{-\lambda^2/n} \le 1 + (-\lambda^2/n) + \cdots$, whereas we need a lower bound?

Comment: @theQman, The Taylor series does many things. For example, if $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$, then $f(x) \geq 1 + x/2$ for all $x$ small enough. The same idea gives a lower bound in this problem.